article class: how to eliminate the pagenumber and let \thepage work
on my .tex I use article documentclass. It (by default) put the page number on bottom of page. But I also use \thepage variable to put page number on top of the page in a specific place.
I would suppress the page number that the article class put on bottom. So i've tried \pagenumbering{gobble} and it works, but it eliminate also \thepage page number variable.
How can I suppress the documentclass {article} page number, but not \thepage variable?

use fancyhdr package and define a page style with empty foot and the page in the page head.

\pagenumbering{gobble} was never a supported construct it just accidentally does something that is sometimes useful. The documented way would be to use \pagestyle{empty} but as I say you don't want an empty page style but one with the number in the head

fancyhdr if you're using a standard class .... If you're managing to put the page number in a specific place, you're using a page style already?

IMHO your question would be clearer, if you'd add a minimal working example of what you've tried and explain there the wanted changes.

It is not that difficult to modify page styles even without fancyhdr.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% random text

\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \def\@oddhead{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}% activate new definition

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}


In case certain pages wind up in plain style:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% random text

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain=\ps@empty
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}


sorry, I don't understund it. Page number still show at beginning...

You said you wanted it at the top of the page (albeit in an unmentioned specific place).

no. I woul not the page number in the page. I use  \thepage variable to put it on a strip at top page. but I would not it in other places! I sould eliminate the page number that the class article put by default

In that case, use \pagestyle{empty} like David Carlilse syuggested,
